# Hibernate search and elastic search analysers for exact search

Tags: java, hibernate, elasticsearch, hibernate-search

I have StandardAnalyser above the field in entity

```
 @Field(name = "myField", index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES, analyzer = @Analyzer(impl = StandardAnalyzer.class)),
```

But I wonder how to then make it possible to:

1) Search by words like: I like bananas -> ["I", "like", "bananas"] (which my analyser currently allows me to do)

2) Search by exact input: "I like bananas" -> "I like bananas" (which StandardAnalyser does not allow and the fitting change would be to impl = KeywordAnalyser)

Should I change my analyser or maybe in java code, based on input (if it starts and ends with double quotes) change the way of searching?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want a phrase query? A phrase query looks for a sequence of tokens, instead of just one token.

```java
Query luceneQuery = queryBuilder.phrase()
    .onField("myField")
    .sentence("I like bananas")
    .createQuery();
```

See https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.11/reference/en-US/html_single/#_phrase_queries

Phrase queries are still sort of "fuzzy", however, since the analyzer is still involved: case will be ignored, etc. It's just about looking for a sequence of (analyzed) tokens.

If you really need exact search, including case sensitivity, you can simply declare two fields:

```java
 @Field(name = "myField", index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES, analyzer = @Analyzer(impl = StandardAnalyzer.class))
 @Field(name = "myField_exact", index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.NO)
```

Then you can target either `myField` or `myField_exact` at query time, depending on your needs.

Of course, you will need to reindex your data before `myField_exact` becomes available.

Comment: I was rather thinking about having StandardAnalyser and at the same time KeywordAnalyser to just make one exception from StandardAnalyser way of working when I put the phrase into double quotes. So far what I found out on elastic discuss there is no way, and maybe better is to have to indices:

https://discuss.elastic.co/t/exact-match-search-on-field-with-standard-analyzer/9617/3